# How do I get the product updated timestamp?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I am trying to display the data and time for the last time the product was updated.

```
<?php

$product = $block->getProduct();

?>

<h1><?php echo $product->getData('spec_sheet'); 
?></h1>

<span><?php echo $product->getUpdated_At();?></span>
```

I am not getting any errors, but it also isn't displaying anything.

Edit:
Moved it to a different template

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product additional attributes template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
    <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product- 
attribute-specs-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('More Information') ?></caption>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block- 
 >escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block- 
 >escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ 
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
<div class="spectab"><?php echo $_product- 
>getData('specification_tab'); ?></div>
<div><?php echo $product->getUpdated_At(); ?></div>
```

Now I get- 
Notice: Undefined variable: product

I changed the last line to

```
<div><?php echo $_product->getUpdated_At(); ?></div>
```

And the error clears but nothing displays.

Answer (score 2):

Try `<?php echo $product->getUpdatedAt(); ?>`

Comment: Same issue. That is the way I tried it first. Just to make sure I tried it that way again and still getting nothing. I did flush cache after each change.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the last template I used this instead-

```
<div><?php echo $_product->getData('updated_at'); ?></div>
```

And it works!